# Как использовать конкретный язык ассемблера при вставках в код С/С++?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, nasm, masm

Я догадываюсь, что в Windows Micsoft Visual Studio используется MASM, в MinGW скорее всего тоже, тогда как в GNU/LINUX - gas, я прав? Хотя знаю, что NASM, например, подходит на все популярные ОС. Можно как-то вручную выбрать язык ассемблера при вставках кода? Скорее всего нужно ассемблер подключать к компилятору С/С++? И какие точно используются языки ассемблера при вставках на разных компиляторах, если я не правильно угадал? Спасибо.

Comment: Вам точно нужны ассемблерные вставки? Если это в целях оптимизации, то стоит сначала сделать профилирование.

Comment: Лучше вообще не использовать вставки, а создавать отдельные единицы трансляции.

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы, но я не за советом пришел, а узнать мнение профессионалов по-поводу моего вопроса.

Comment: да, gcc использует gas (точнее его небольшую модификацию - GNU inline assembler, MSVS - использует masm. Я нигде не видел возможность указать другой ассемблер. И похоже, для gcc такой возможности "из коробки" нет, только передать компилятору ассемблерного кода дополнительные параметры и выбрать стиль  (interl/att).

Comment: MinGW - использует тот же ассемблер, что и обычный GCC.

Answer (score -1):

Если под понятием "язык ассемблера" Вы подразумеваете тип процессора то используя `define` можно разделить одну ассемблерную вставку для разных процессоров, если под этим понятием вы подрузумеваете синтаксис [intel](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) или [AT&T](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) то используя `define` так же можно разделить одну и туже вставку для разного синтаксиса.

Comment: по моему, автор вопроса очень точно определил, что он "подразумевает"